# How to use WSDL file, parse SOAP message?

Tags: eclipse, web-services, parsing, soap, wsdl

This is my first post here(pardon me if I'm vague).
Actually I've got a wsdl file (which have soap requests, schema, generates pojo) and my task is to 
1) Integrate that with eclipse .
2) Send the request to the server.
3) get the response back.
4) And parse the response in Java.
And I'm not at all aware of where to start. Someone suggested of using Apache axis with eclipse (I'm not aware of that too).
Thank you for your help, And also please suggest what is the best way of parsing and how to parse a SOAP message that way in JAVA.

A demo will be so much appreciated.
Thank You.... and sorry if I'm expecting too much, I'm newbie :)

Comment: Try to look for a library to handle soap first

Answer (score 0):

1. Create auto generated classes from WSDL. You can use various tools that help in generate classes from WSDL file ex: JAVAtoWSDL or ApacheAxis.
2. Once classes has been generated then you can parse request and create response with JAXB, that is marshall and unmarshall.

Comment: Thank you, but that's a bit too short for some newbie like me to understand.